# Why are my scripts not loading in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have no idea why my JS scripts are not loading in WordPress. They are in my functions file.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    function JS_Registeration(){
        wp_enqueue_script("main_JS", get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
        wp_enqueue_script("custom_JS", get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
    }

    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","JS_Registeration");

?>
```

Comment: is it a child theme? then you should use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/

Comment: hmm not a child theme

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** the  was past the  tag. It should be right before.